# How to set a property value based on other property in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema as exemple:

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  categoryId: {type: Number},
  title: {type: String, default: "standard"},
})
```

I want that the category with categoryId equal 1, must always be "standard", and if the title is not specified, it will assign the categoryId = 1. Is there any way to do that in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we have two cases here:

1. > category with categoryId equal 1, must always be "standard"

You could use a pre hook, the code would be like this:

```
  const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    categoryId: {type: Number},
    title: {type: String, default: "standard"},
  })

  categorySchema.pre('save', function (){
    if(this.categoryId === 1){
      this.title = "standard";
    }
  })

  const categoryModel =  mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
  const category = new categoryModel({title: 'Greaat', categoryId: 1});
  await category.save();
```

2. > if the title is not specified, it will assign the categoryId = 1

With your current code it shouldn't work because you're indicating with  `default: "standard"` that if a title is not specified you have to assign **standard** as default, so you should leave the default property and manage it in the pre hook to achieve that but that logic seems to me complicated maybe you need to think a little bit better what is the problem, because this kind of solutions are overcomplicated IMHO